# Nuxt Fatal Error when running npm run generate

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, nuxt.js

I'm basically running `npm run generate` in jenkins build

This is my current configuration:

```
npm install

npm test

npm run generate

// then upload dist/ to s3 for static hosting
```

I'm getting

```
   ╭────────────────────────╮
   │                        │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error   │
   │                        │
   │                        │
   │                        │
   ╰────────────────────────╯

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vs_admin@1.0.0 generate: `nuxt generate`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the vs_admin@1.0.0 generate script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I'm thinking it cannot find the nuxt in my jenkins server, but I put the nuxt package inside my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "TEST APP",
  "author": "STB Tech Dev",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build --spa",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "test": "mocha --recursive -r esm"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@johmun/vue-tags-input": "^2.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "config": "^3.0.1",
    "cookieparser": "^0.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.5",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.0.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.4.3",
    "repl": "^0.1.3",
    "sinon": "^7.2.4",
    "vue-bootstrap-toggle": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-clamp": "^0.2.1",
    "vue-date-pick": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.6.4",
    "vue-select": "^2.5.1",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.17.0",
    "vuejs-noty": "^0.1.3",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "nyc": "^13.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: does it work locally?

Comment: I can run the npm run generate locally in my machine, but in Jenkins it's fatal error

Comment: try to run build, maybe there will be better error

Comment: I've run into similar issues regarding devDependencies not being installed in Jenkins. If you put everything in your devDependencies into your dependencies instead, does it work? If you only install production dependencies (delete `node_modules` and run `npm install --production`), does the build succeed?

Comment: can you show the full error log info?